# Why cannot a dynamically sized array be allocated on stack?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, allocation

In C, we all learned that:

```
int i[500]; // Array of 500 integers on stack
int *i = malloc(sizeof(int) * 500); // Array of 500 integers on heap
```

Stack size grows and shrinks as functions push and pop variables from it. But why cannot a dynamically size array be pushed and popped from stack?

Comment: They can, since 1999 :) Also some systems provide [`alloca()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca) just for that.

Comment: Besides [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) some systems have a function for dynamic allocation on the stack called [`alloca`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html)

Comment: @Danvil how does that discussion address my question?

Comment: note that the C standard does not specify how/when the stack or heap should be used, or if they should even exist (in fact, the words "stack" and "heap" don't even appear in it). Instead it talks about static, automatic, and allocated storage duration, and leaves the specifics of the memory layout to the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they can:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an
>   extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++. These arrays are
>   declared like any other automatic arrays, but with a length that is
>   not a constant expression. The storage is allocated at the point of
>   declaration and deallocated when the block scope containing the
>   declaration exits. For example:

```
 FILE *
 concat_fopen (char *s1, char *s2, char *mode)
 {
   char str[strlen (s1) + strlen (s2) + 1];
   strcpy (str, s1);
   strcat (str, s2);
   return fopen (str, mode);
 }
```

Simple test:

```
$ cat testarray.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  size_t n = atol(argv[1]), i;
  printf("array size: %lu\n", n);

  int a[n];

  for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    a[i] = i;
  }

  printf("%d\n", a[0]);

  return 0;
}

$ ./a.out 100000
array size: 100000
0
$ ./a.out 1000000
array size: 1000000
0
$ ./a.out 10000000
array size: 10000000
Segmentation fault
$ ./a.out 100000000
array size: 100000000
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: `char str[strlen (s1) + strlen (s2) + 1]` is allocated on stack, not heap?

Comment: @BlackMamba: Yes, it happens on automatic storage (which in most architectures is stack memory). Essentially it's syntactic sugar for `alloca`.

Answer (score 1):

If array's length will not change since first allocation, then it can be allocated on stack, even when it's size is not known at time of compilation. C99 supports this under the name *variable length arrays*. Previous versions of the language could simulate the same with non-standard `alloca` function.

However, the term “dynamically sized array” usually assumes that array can grow later again and again, indefinitely until there's still memory available, and such thing is not truly possible on stack, because the stack space after the array may be already taken by another function call.